# Modify file contents based github PR's branch name automatically

Tags: git, github, version-control, workflow, github-actions

I want to set up a automatic way in Github which does something like this:

When a PR is merged, github should run a script which can modify few small numbers in a file. But the numbers should be based on the branch name.

For example:
branch name : `A_some_branch_name`

Then the script checks the branch name and get `file.txt` and `line 1 : version:1.1` add `1` to the last number. To `line 1 : version:1.2`.

**Preferably I don't want to use github actions.**

Comment: I'm pretty sure that github actions is the only way to do something like this. If you were doing it locally, you could use git hooks, but I don't know of any other way other than github actions with github

Comment: It might be helpful to ask: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @AlectoIrenePerez every pr needs to modify version number so to avoid conflicts github should do it easily, based on branch name

Comment: Most major projects typically only update version numbers when publishing a new version, which is a manual process. This is why major projects have a development branch: when the version is updated, it's updated on the development branch, and then merged into the main branch

Comment: Yes I realize that, but our process is bit different therefore it is required. If u have any other resource where I can get more informaiton, please share that thanks.